# If last elements has class

Tags: jquery

I want to remove last elements if they have a specific class. For examples :

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="items"></div>
   <div class="items"></div>
   <div class="items"></div>
   <div class="items"></div>
   <div class="items empty<"></div>
   <div class="items empty"></div>
   <div class="items empty"></div>
   <div class="items empty"></div>
</div>
```

I add the last elements with an automatic on release function, but I want to add 4 empty items only if the last for is not already empty.

So I think a function like this (but it doesn't work) :

```
if (!($(".items").slice(-4).hasClass("empty")) ) { //do nothing }

else {
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have try using .eq() for element index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.eq()` jquery's method can accept negative index. Setting this index to -1 give you last item:

```
if($('.items').eq(-1).is(':not(.empty)')){ 
   //add for new emty div to gride
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a "do nothing if-clause" do this:

```
if(!$('.items:last').hasClass('empty')) {
   var div = "<div class='items empty'></div>";
   $(".grid").append(div)
             .append(div)
             .append(div)
             .append(div);
}
```

Short and concise, plus it won't keep the next developer or yourself scratching your head with "what did he mean by //do nothing".

## edit

This a mix of mine and Christophs solution.
What this does is that it's minimizing the load you put on the query engine so that you don't have to query the DOM several times but does so instead in one call.
This is optimizing a lot but a good practice to have in the back of ones head.

Comment: I like this one best. For extra optimization you might want to do `.append(div + div + div + div)` instead (one single append call).

Comment: Well, one can optimize a lot :) The point is not to confuse the OP :) But yeah, I hadn't thought of your solution, it's pretty cool!

Comment: This is nice, but it only check if the last item is empty. And I want to check if the 4 last items are empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
while( $('.item.empty').length < 4 ) {
    $('.grid').append('<div class="items empty"></div>');
}
```

This way you'll always have 4 empty items at the end of your grid.
Also avoid the `//do nothing` part that isn't helping code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:last` selector:

```
if ($(".items:last").hasClass("empty") ){ 
    //do nothing 
} else {
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>");
}
```

It will work for every number of elements, not only for 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( $(".items:last").hasClass('empty') )
{
  //do nothing
}
else
{
  $(".grid").append("<div class='items empty'></div>("<div class='items empty'></div>("<div class='items empty'></div>("<div class='items empty'></div>");
}
```